# Extra space before the first row of an array

Tags: arrays

Why is there so much space before my array's first row? How can I fix it (as I don't believe that this is its default behaviour)?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{parskip}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont
[
  Ligatures=TeX,
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*,
  BoldFont=*Bold,
  ItalicFont=*It,
  BoldItalicFont=*BoldIt,
  Mapping=tex-text
]{GFSArtemisia}

\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{GFSArtemisia.otf}

\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}

\setmathfont[range=\varnothing]{Asana-Math.otf}

\setmathfont[range=\int]{latinmodern-math.otf}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\left[\begin{array}{c c c}
g_{11} & g_{12} & g_{13}\\
g_{21} & g_{22} & g_{23}\\
g_{21} & g_{32} & g_{33}
\end{array}\right]
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

**The list of files** (not from the MWE but from my normal preamble)

```
article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class

size12.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)

geometry.sty    2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry

keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)

ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)

ifvtex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)

ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional

parskip.sty    2001/04/09 non-zero parskip adjustments

amsmath.sty    2013/01/14 v2.14 AMS math features

amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01

amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0

amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d

amsopn.sty    1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names

unicode-math.sty    2013/05/04 v0.7e Unicode maths in XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX

ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)

expl3.sty    2014/01/07 v4646 L3 Experimental code bundle wrapper

l3names.sty    2014/01/04 v4640 L3 Namespace for primitives

l3bootstrap.sty    2014/01/04 v4640 L3 Experimental bootstrap code

etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)

l3basics.sty    2014/01/04 v4642 L3 Basic definitions

l3expan.sty    2014/01/04 v4642 L3 Argument expansion

l3tl.sty    2013/12/27 v4625 L3 Token lists

l3seq.sty    2013/12/14 v4623 L3 Sequences and stacks

l3int.sty    2013/08/02 v4583 L3 Integers

l3quark.sty    2013/12/14 v4623 L3 Quarks

l3prg.sty    2014/01/04 v4642 L3 Control structures

l3clist.sty    2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Comma separated lists

l3token.sty    2013/08/25 v4587 L3 Experimental token manipulation

l3prop.sty    2013/12/14 v4623 L3 Property lists

l3msg.sty    2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Messages

l3file.sty    2013/10/13 v4596 L3 File and I/O operations

l3skip.sty    2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Dimensions and skips

l3keys.sty    2013/12/08 v4614 L3 Experimental key-value interfaces

l3fp.sty    2014/01/04 v4642 L3 Floating points

l3box.sty    2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Experimental boxes

l3coffins.sty    2013/12/14 v4624 L3 Coffin code layer

l3color.sty    2012/08/29 v4156 L3 Experimental color support

l3luatex.sty    2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Experimental LuaTeX-specific functions

l3candidates.sty    2014/01/06 v4643 L3 Experimental additions to l3kernel

xparse.sty    2013/12/31 v4634 L3 Experimental document command parser

l3keys2e.sty    2013/12/31 v4634 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys

fontspec.sty    2013/05/20 v2.3c Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX

fontspec-patches.sty    2013/05/20 v2.3c Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX

fixltx2e.sty    2006/09/13 v1.1m fixes to LaTeX

fontspec-xetex.sty    2013/05/20 v2.3c Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX

fontenc.sty

eu1enc.def    2010/05/27 v0.1h Experimental Unicode font encodings

eu1lmr.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern

xunicode.sty    2011/09/09 v0.981 provides access to latin accents and many 

other characters in Unicode lower plane

eu1lmss.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern

graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)

graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
xetex.def    2013/04/29 v0.96 LaTeX color/graphics driver for XeTeX (RRM/JK)

fontspec.cfg

catchfile.sty    2011/03/01 v1.6 Catch the contents of a file (HO)

infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)

ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)

etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)

fix-cm.sty    2006/09/13 v1.1m fixes to LaTeX

ts1enc.def    2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file

filehook.sty    2011/10/12 v0.5d Hooks for input files

unicode-math-xetex.sty    

unicode-math-table.tex

babel.sty    2013/12/03 3.9h The Babel package

english.ldf    2012/08/20 v3.3p English support from the babel system

greek.ldf    2013/12/03 v1.8a Greek support for the babel system

greek-euenc.def    2013/12/02 0.11.1 Greek LICRs for XeTeX and LuaTeX

greek-fontenc.def    2013/11/28 v0.11 Common Greek font encoding definitions

xgreek-fixes.def

listings.sty    2013/08/26 1.5b (Carsten Heinz)

lstmisc.sty    2013/08/26 1.5b (Carsten Heinz)

listings.cfg    2013/08/26 1.5b listings configuration

multicol.sty    2011/06/27 v1.7a multicolumn formatting (FMi)

xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive

colortbl.sty    2012/02/13 v1.0a Color table columns (DPC)

array.sty    2008/09/09 v2.4c Tabular extension package (FMi)

dvipsnam.def    1999/02/16 v3.0i Driver-dependant file (DPC,SPQR)

svgnam.def    2007/01/21 v2.11 Predefined colors according to SVG 1.1 (UK)

longtable.sty    2004/02/01 v4.11 Multi-page Table package (DPC)

tikz.sty    2010/10/13 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.76)

pgf.sty    2008/01/15 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.12)

pgfrcs.sty    2010/10/25 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.24)

everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)

pgfrcs.code.tex

pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)

pgfsys.sty    2010/06/30 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.37)

pgfsys.code.tex

pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2008/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.7)

pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)

pgfcore.code.tex

pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)

pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.1)

pgffor.sty    2010/03/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.18)

pgfkeys.sty    

pgfkeys.code.tex

pgffor.code.tex

tikz.code.tex

t3cmr.fd    2001/12/31 TIPA font definitions
```

Comment: Using your code, I don't get the extra spacing (using TeX Live2014).

Comment: I tested your example with lualtex and xelatex (texlive 2014) and got no space with either

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I use xelatex too. In mine it appears for sure as I printed a paper with an array that had the same problem. Except the image :p

Comment: add `\listfiles` to your preamble and then add the list that appears at the end of the log file to your question then people can see the version of all packages used

Comment: Neither with me using xelatex and lualatex (MiKTeX 2014)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle done!

Comment: It seems you have an out-to-date distro. Please update it.

Comment: Install Vanilla TeX Live. http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/27635

Comment: @karlkoeller Thanks, do I need to uninstall my current version?

Comment: Yes, that's the best thing to do.

Comment: @karlkoeller I have updated my TeX distribution and everything is exactly the same regarding the table...

Comment: Could you please minimize your code if all the fonts are not needed here? Does the problem still persist?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is only reproducible if

```
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
```

is added.

Add also

```
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.6}
```