# ShareLaTeX maintenance

Tags: sharelatex

I have been using ShareLaTeX for a long time and I like it very much, but lately it seems to me that it is not up-to-date.

I had asked two questions [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225593/extra-space-before-the-first-row-of-an-array), [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227545/spacing-in-a-two-column-document-in-sharelatex) in here some time ago and obviously the answer to both of them was that my TeX distribution was outdated. The only thing is that they were written in ShareLaTeX (actually the first one wasn't but this exact thing is happening in ShareLaTeX also).

Currently this issue hasn't been resolved. Is there a problem with the site? Is it still maintained? If it is how can I send a request to the maintainers to update the packages?

Comment: Send them an email (or use their contact form on their homepage!) - the authors were active on their open source branch https://github.com/sharelatex/sharelatex 7 days ago, so I doubt they have abandoned it.

Comment: @Adam did you ever get a reply? I've also been using ShareLaTeX for a long time but have noticed the servers go down a lot more than they used to.

Comment: @Blue7 Unfortunately I haven't got a reply. As you are interested too, if I ever get I will post a comment here.

Comment: TeX.SX isn't really a place for reports like this… :( It's not really about TeX systems in a way that we can help with (devil's advocate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108497/17423). You can always find this sort of information on the project's homepage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All maintenance issues should be addressed here: https://github.com/sharelatex/sharelatex/issues

This site appears to be active as their have been opened, closed, and discussed issues during the last week.

Comment: Thank you. I have sent an email and I will see if I get a reply. If not I will report in their repository on github.

Answer (score 3):

ShareLaTeX Founder here:

We are still very active and are still growing both the team and userbase. We will be updating to TeX Live 2015 very soon. Sorry if your packages are out of date, we maybe should start updating the tex version more often.

In future the best thing todo is let us know you are having these problems by emailing us. If we get a lot of emails about something like this we are made aware that is is an issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response and I appreciate the effort you put into the site. I have emailed you about this issue. :)

Comment: @henry.oswald If you have time, could you please have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308929/tcolorbox-header-error-with-bredelebeamer-class ?  I cannot reproduce it with a local distribution, could this be a sharelatex problem?