# tcolorbox header error with Bredelebeamer class

Tags: beamer, tcolorbox, sharelatex

I'm working with `tcolorbox` package, and i'm trying to replicate this
[image: Header_tcolorbox],

when I compile and no use it, runs without error, but when I'm trying to use it, it fails.

My code is something like this:

```
\documentclass{Bredelebeamer}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
...
\begin{document}
...
%% this code comes from tColorbox Documentation Section 10.2.3 Page 153
\newtcolorbox{BoxRafa}[2][]
{enhanced,
before skip=2mm,after skip=2mm,
colback=black!5,colframe=black!50,boxrule=0.2mm,
attach boxed title to top left =
    {xshift=1cm,yshift*=1mm-\tcboxedtitleheight},
    varwidth boxed title*=-3cm,
    boxed title style={frame code={
                        \path[fill=tcbcol@back!30!black]
                            ([yshift=-1mm,xshift=-1mm]frame.north west)  
                            arc[start angle=0,end angle=180,radius=1mm]
                            ([yshift=-1mm,xshift=1mm]frame.north east)
                            arc[start angle=180,end angle=0,radius=1mm];
                        \path[left color=tcbcol@back!60!black,right color = tcbcol@back!60!black,
                            middle color = tcbcol@back!80!black]
                            ([xshift=-2mm]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=2mm]frame.north east)
                            [rounded corners=1mm]-- ([xshift=1mm,yshift=-1mm]frame.north east) 
                            -- (frame.south east) -- (frame.south west)
                            -- ([xshift=-1mm,yshift=-1mm]frame.north west)
                            [sharp corners]-- cycle;
                            },interior engine=empty,
                    },
fonttitle=\bfseries,
title={#2},#1}
...
\section{SomeTitleSection}

\begin{frame}{SomeTitleFrame)}

\begin{BoxRafa}[colbacktitle = green]{Title Box}
    Some text ...
\end{BoxRafa} %% This is line 90

\end{frame}
...
\end{document}
```

And send this error:
[image: Erro_tcolorbox]

Does any one know what I'm doing wrong???
I'm using `ShareLatex`, do I need to add another `.cls` or `.sty`??

Comment: Where do we get `beamerrafa`? If I use `beamer` class and add `\usepackage{tcolorbox}`, it does work

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I've already edit my question, the base Class i'm using is `Bredelebeamer` and i'm working on `ShareLateX`

Comment: Bredelebeamer is also not available for me, the `ShareLaTeX` information is also not really useful

Comment: I googled for this `Bredelebeamer` thing and with the version from https://git.framasoft.org/Framatophe/BredeleDiapo/tree/master your MWE compiles without errors.

Comment: Compiling the MWE locally with texlive2015 works fine, but I can confirm that it does not work on sharelatex.

Comment: @samcarter: Do you want to provide an answer or shall we vote to close?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I would tend to close it as "probably a problem of sharelatex", but having already voted once, I cannot close it a second time.  As I have no idea would might go wrong there, I can not provide a useful answer.

Comment: @samcarter: Unfortunately I used the wrong closing reason -- I had to retract and wait until the grace period is over to vote again

Comment: ShareLaTeX has a reasonably new version of texlive installed, it gets updated every few months. If you are using an old project it might be linked to an older version of tex live. Otherwise you can include the .cls and .sty files manually for the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a version problem of your project. Sharelatex seems to choose the tex version based on when you created your project - meaning that existing projects will not automatically be updated to the current version.

At the time this question was asked, I created a project on Sharelatex which confirmed the error: https://de.sharelatex.com/project/5733508c3cc17735563bcf58 As seen from the log files, it was using `texlive2015`.

Today I tried again with a new project (https://de.sharelatex.com/project/594404eb58cdd50519fe7002) and it works fine, while the old project still exhibits the error. From the log files, the new project is now using `texlive2016`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @samcarter, I've been dealing with this for months because i always use ShareLatex and at this case i had to use a desktop version. So,  should i create another project? to compile without error. Or is any other way force to use another `Tex` version?

Comment: @RafaBG Creating a new project might be easiest. Download your old as .zip file, create a new project and upload the .zip file.